# ASP.NET Enter key triggering unwanted button

Tags: asp.net, button, postback

I have this on the top of a page (in MasterPage.master)

```
    <asp:Panel ID="panSearch" runat="server">
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSearch" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/iconSearch.gif" onclick="btnSearch_Click" />
    </asp:Panel>
```

The button keeps getting fired when I press the enter key on another TextBox down the page (in an aspx page)

```
<input type="text" id="txtTagName">
<input type="button" value="Tag" id="btnAddTagOk">
```

I couldn't find any JavaScript that does that.

Anyone has any idea why it's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hitting enter will submit the default form. If you have several controls which you want control over the enter button you need to hook in javascript on the control to intercept the enter key press, and then do your own logic.

Something like this

```
<input type="text" id="txtTagName" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnAddTagOk').click()"/>
```

Comment: I see, so you need event.preventDefault(); on keydown. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you might have some other button with its type as `type="submit"`. The browser by default submits the form when `enter` is pressed on textboxes.

you might want to try following on your `asp:panel`

```
<asp:Panel ID="panSearch" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearch">

</asp:Panel>
```